# problem on ubuntu bridges installation

Tags: networking, network-bridge, virt-manager

I'm following the instructions, but it is not working.

Here is my original `00-installer-config.yaml` file:

```
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  ethernets:
    enp2s0:
      dhcp4: true
    enxc21a33ea90c1:
      dhcp4: true
  version: 2
```

...and this is how it looks after edits:

```
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  ethernets:
    enp2s0:
      dhcp4: no
    enxc21a33ea90c1:
      dhcp4: no
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  bridges:
          br0:
          interfaces: [enp2s0]
          addresses: [192.168.8.108/24]
          nameservers:
                  addresses:  [8.8.8.8,4.4.4.4]
```

I got this error after running `sudo netplan apply`:

```
/etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml:11:15: Error in network definition: expected mapping (check indentation)
          br0:
```

Can anyone advise what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Netplan (using YAML) is picky about indentation. Try formatting the file exactly like this, and see if it works:

```
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  ethernets:
    enp2s0:
      dhcp4: no
    enxc21a33ea90c1:
      dhcp4: no
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  bridges:
    br0:
      interfaces: [enp2s0]
      dhcp4: no
      addresses: [192.168.8.108/24]
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4]
```

The main error I can spot is that you lack indentation between `br0:` and `interfaces:`.

Also, not that the secondary Google DNS is `8.8.4.4`. and not `4.4.4.4`.